Why gtest is generating Uninteresting mock function call warning?
I've written a gtest for a class that uses a Singleton by calling a method of a public member instance that reads a file. I've mocked the class of the public member and I am using ON_CALL to populate the json file.
My whole code is this:
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#include <cstddef>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;

class MockedUtil
{
    public:
    MockedUtil(){};
    ~MockedUtil(){};
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, readJSONFile, (const std::string &filePath, json &j));
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, writeJSONFile, (const std::string &filePath, const json &j));
};

template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
  static T& get()
  {
    static T s(token{});

    // return the instance
    return s;
  }
  // copy constructor
  Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;

  // assignment operator
  Singleton& operator=(const Singleton) = delete;

  // move constructor
  Singleton(const Singleton&&) = delete;

  // Move assign
  Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&&) = delete;

protected:
  // constructor
  Singleton();

  // destructor
  virtual ~Singleton();
  struct token
  {};
};

template<typename T>
Singleton<T>::Singleton()
{}

template<typename T>
Singleton<T>::~Singleton()
{}

class MyTest_mockfunctioncall_Test;
class ConcreteSingleton : public Singleton<ConcreteSingleton>
{
private:
  FRIEND_TEST(::MyTest, mockfunctioncall);
  std::string private_key;
  int val = -1;

public:
  ConcreteSingleton(token){};
  MockedUtil wrapper;
  bool readJSON(const std::string& settings, json& my_json)
  {
    this->private_key = "MyKey";
    const std::string path {"MyJson.json"};
    bool result =
        wrapper.readJSONFile(path, my_json);
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout<<"Unable to read json file\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!my_json[this->private_key].contains(settings))
    {
        std::cout<<"Setting is not present in my_json\n";
        std::cout<< my_json.dump(1, '\t') << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    my_json[settings] = my_json[this->private_key][settings];
    return true;
  }
};

class ClassToBeTested{
  public:
  ClassToBeTested() = default;
  int value;
  
  ~ClassToBeTested() = default;
  void foo()
  {
    value = -1;
    std::cout<<__FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__<<"; value: "<<value<<std::endl;
    json my_json = nullptr;
    std::cout<<" before calling\n";
    const std::string key {"my_key"};
    bool result = ConcreteSingleton::get().readJSON(key,my_json);
    if(result){
        value = my_json[key];
        std::cout<<"LINE COVERED\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"LINE NOT COVERED\n";
    }
    std::cout<<__FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__<<"; value: "<<value<<std::endl;
  }
};

TEST(MyTest, mockfunctioncall)
{
  auto& singleton = ConcreteSingleton::get();
  ClassToBeTested object;
  json my_json = nullptr;
  const std::string mystr{"MyJson"};
  ON_CALL(
    singleton.wrapper,
    readJSONFile(::testing::_, ::testing::_))
    .WillByDefault(
      [&](const std::string& filePath, json& j)
      {
        std::cout<<"inside lambda\n";
        j = R"( {"MyKey": {"my_key": 2}} )"_json;;
        return true;
      });
  
  object.foo();
  EXPECT_EQ(object.value, 2);
}

The test is passing, but when here is my output with the Uninteresting mock function call.
test_file.cpp:105; value: -1
before calling
inside lambda
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - taking default action specified at:
test_file.cpp:128:
    Function call: readJSONFile(@0x7ffe1fea0ad0 "MyJson.json", @0x7ffe1fea0b60 null)
          Returns: true
NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.  See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#knowing-when-to-expect-useoncall for details.
LINE COVERED
test_file.cpp:118; value: 2

I don't understand this warning: I am using ON_CALL just to populate the json object manually instead of reading it from file. Why is generating Uninteresting mock function call? Should I ignore it or there is a way to solve this?

ON_CALL defines default behavior it doesn't set any expectations. EXPECT_CALL is adding proper expectation that mock should be called.

Exactly, since my biggest concern is to populate the json, I'm using ON_CALL instead of EXPECT_CALL: is this a problem?

It depends on test intention. I use ON_CALL in SetUp to define default behavior of mock. Then in test I'm adding simple EXPECT_CALL which only do not have complex processing.

BTW singletons are one of this things which are misused and are not testable (it is best not use them at all)! The way you wrote this test is bad and as you will progress with this code you will see a problem.

I know singletones are bad and that with it I am violating the explicit dependency principle (i.e., not using injection) so there is not anything I can do about the classes. Considering this, if you have suggestions on the test part, they are more than welcome.

Better version: https://godbolt.org/z/dfcPjxMc8

I didn't wrote "singletons are bad" - I've wrote they "are misused" (this is another topic).

Anyway back to the original question, is the warning normal when using ON_CALL inside the test?

@roschach It's a normal warning when you don't use EXPECT_CALL. Whether or not you use ON_CALL is not related to this warning.

I've already explained this in first comment.

If you don't care about expectations on the mocked singleton you can just replace MockedUtil wrapper; with ::testing::NiceMock<MockedUtil> wrapper;
